# What is the significance of "Do not change a loop variable inside a for loop block"?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, standards

One of the coding standards in C++ is "Do not change a loop variable inside a for loop block".

What are all the advantages of following this rule, and vice versa?

I am trying to split a long sentence into smaller sentences with a max character limit (21 chars) as delimiter.

`tokens` (a `std::vector`) consists of all the strings:

```
 for (size_t index = 0; index < totalTokens ; ++index) {
         std::string temp(str1 + STRING_SINGLESPACE + tokens[index]);
         if (temp.length() < maxcharacterlimit) {
             str1 = temp;
         } else {
             subsystemlist.push_back(str1);
             str1 = STRING_EMPTY;
             --index;
         }
     }
```

Inside the `for` loop, I am changing  `index` with `--index`.

Comment: What standard are you referring to?

Comment: This code snippet could lead to a infinite loop

Comment: There is no language named C/C++. There are numerous coding standards for just about every programming language. So, the background info in your question is all very questionable. However the advice you got, from whereever, was sound. Don't do that.

Comment: Never read of this coding standard. But putting all loop logic into the head is  good practice to detect faults of infinity loops easier.

Comment: The idiom for for-loops is a definite, obvious number of iterations. If the number of loops is conditional or dynamic, other tools like `while` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Coding standards usually come with a rationale for each rule so you can understand why the rule is there. For example, the [ISO C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) put the rationale [right at the top of the rule statement](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-loop-counter).

Answer (score 4):

Coding standards aren't absolute rules, they're guidelines. Usually if you're updating the iteration variable inside the loop, it's a mistake. For instance, earlier today I saw a question where someone wrote something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i++]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

`array[i++]` was wrong, he meant `array[i+1]`. Because of this error, he was incrementing the variable extra times and skipping over elements.

But there can be legitimate reasons.

For instance, your code wants to process the same element again when it starts a new element of `subsystemlist`.

Another common situation where you might do this is a loop that processes command line arguments. The main loop increments the argument index, but if an option has parameters after it, you'll increment the argument index additional times to skip over them. (Although these days one normally uses a library function like `getopts()` to automate much of this process.)